# Migrating from EJB with Spring to POJO

Tags: java, spring, pojo, ejb-2.x

While migrating from EJB with spring to POJO , I read every where that just changing this configuration will work :

```
<bean id="sapFeedBean" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="jndiName" value="ejb/sapBean" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="false" />
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.aa.inflightsales.sap.SapBusiness" />
    <property name="lookupHomeOnStartup" value="false" />
</bean>
```

but how to do this , I am trying to create bean of the POJO class , but how can I define the business interface , as interface injection is not supported by spring.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the business methods in this interface which should be implemented by the business class and when you need it just use a reference to the interface with the convenient annotation and the framework will inject the implementation.